# Apex Callout to Rest API throws error

Tags: apex, rest-api, callout, httprequest

I need your advice on testing the integration of third party Rest API from apex like below

```
    public class Testing {
    public final String clientId = ‘xxxxxxxxxxxx’;
    public final String clientSecret = ‘xxxxxxxxxx’;

    public String getD365Customer(){
    String reqbody = ‘grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=’+clientId+’&client_secret=’+clientSecret;
    Http h = new Http();
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setBody(reqbody);
    req.setMethod(‘POST’);
    req.setEndpoint(‘https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant/oauth2/token’);
    HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
    deserializeResponse resp1 = (deserializeResponse)JSON.deserialize(res.getbody(),deserializeResponse.class);
    String atoken = resp1.access_token;
    System.debug(‘Access Token=========’ + atoken);
    //return atoken;

    Http http1 = new Http();
    HttpRequest req1 = new HttpRequest();
    req1.setEndpoint(‘https://dev-mca/data/Customers’);
    req1.setMethod(‘GET’);
    req1.setHeader(‘Authorization’,’Bearer ‘+atoken);
    HttpResponse res1 = http1.send(req1);
    System.debug(‘Response Body=========’ + res1.getBody());
    return res1.getBody();
    }
    public class deserializeResponse
    {
    public String token_type;
    public String expires_in;
    public String ext_expires_in;
    public String expires_on;
    public String not_before;
    public String resource;
    public String access_token;
    }}
```

But I am getting the error like

> Line: 23, Column: 1
>   System.UnexpectedException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid start or end

I wanted to check the Callouts directly from Apex so I can use the Named Credentials but I am just stuck here. Not sure if I am missing something.

Comment: have you verified that you can call the endpoint with a tool like Postman. this usually is the way one debugs these issues - get it working using a simpler tool

Comment: Yes I am able to test it using PostMan

Comment: [googling your error](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/issues/2617) provides hint the issue is in the req1.setHeader(..) contents. Does the recipient need any other header values?

Comment: what's on line 23?

Comment: It's the send.
I'm seeing this in a certain callout as well. Intermittently unfortunately, so @cropredy might be on to something.